# Setting n entries of matrix to zero

Tags: r, algorithm

I would like to set `n` entries of matrix to zero, below is my attempt to solve this problem, by generation uique pairs of integers.

How to generate unique pairs of integers from uniform distribution `(x,y)`, example if we want three pairs with x and y from 1:1000 range, then one of solutions is : 
(1,888),(743,743),(743,4)
if I use     `cbind(sample(1:1000,100,replace=TRUE),sample(1:1000,100,replace=TRUE))` to generate `100` pairs I risk, that they could repeat several times. Fow to make it in vectorized manner (without loops) ?

**Pairs can't repeat, but their elements can, example :**
(1,2),(2,1),(1,1),(2,2),(23,23),(86,52) is proper output for range 1:100 and six pairs

Comment: to clarify, you allow the pairs repeat, e.g. (1,2) (1,2), but don't allow the elements of a pair repeat, e.g. (1,1), (2,2)?

Comment: @Randy Lai no, I want the opposite

Comment: Does `replace=TRUE` mean you're sampling with replacement? if so, you could just choose randomly in the interval `[1, 1000*1000]` without replacement, and then convert these to pairs.

Comment: Oh, since you were using `replace=TRUE`. I thought you allow the pairs repeat.

Comment: @Patrick87 sorry, I misread your comment...

Comment: QPatrick87 yes, but I need certain number of unique realizations of two dimensional uniform distribution over given set of pairs of integers

Comment: @Qbik I'm having trouble parsing your comment. Why would what I'm suggesting not work? Step 1: Choose 100 numbers between 1 and a million. Step 2: Convert each number to a pair of numbers. I don't know whether there's a vector operation for step 2, but for step 1, it would just be `sample(1:1000000,100,replace=FALSE)`, right?

Comment: So you already have a set to work with, say, S = {(1,1), (1,2), (2,2), (3,1) ... } ?

Comment: @ Patrick87 this is only subproblwm of bigger one, I need this to zero n entries in some matrices in uniformly random way over all entries, your method will zero only one element in row (or column if choosen)

Comment: @Qbik, I think Patrick's method actually works

Comment: @Qbik I'm still trying to understand what's wrong with my method. Do you have more requirements than in the question? Can you think of an output that my method wouldn't give, or would give with a different probability?

Comment: @Qbik, if what you want is to zero some entries of a matrix, there is a easier way. You can just do `A[sample(1000*1000, 100, replace=FALSE)] = 0`. Since the elements are extracted columnwisely, your don't have to convert the index into the (row, col) pair.

Comment: @Randy Lai I see, I'll modify my question, so you would answer it

Comment: @Randy Lai now you can post your answer

Comment: @Qbik, I posted an answer.  `sample.int` should be faster than `sample`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you want is to zero some entries of a matrix, there is a easier way. You can just do

```
A[sample.int(1000*1000, 100, replace=FALSE)] = 0
```

where `A` is your matrix.
Since the elements are extracted columnwisely, your don't have to convert the index into the (row, col) pair.

Comment: accepted do to discussion, see comments below question

Answer (score 3):

You can sample integers and then map integers to pairs like this:

```
v <- sample.int(1000^2, size = 100, replace = F)
foo <- function(x) cbind(((x-1) %/% 10) + 1, ((x-1) %% 10) + 1)
foo(v)
```

This keeps you from having to create the entire list to sample from.

Answer (score 1):

Following is the pseudocode for what you want.

```
Store M x N matrix --> ArrayM of one dimension and size M x N

For i = 1 to n    // n is the number of zeros you want

    Generate RandomInteger in the interval [1, M x N - i]
    Set aside the (row,col) coordinates of the element as a Zero element
    ReCreate ArrayM, now of size M x N - 1 containing remaining elements (and their original x,y addresses)
    // you dont have to recreate it, you can implement it using some linked list

 Loop i
```